# How to preserve indentation using Chef::Util::FileEdit functions?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

The question is fairly simple and I couldn't find anything related to indentation inside the [FileEdit](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/chef/Chef/Util/FileEdit) documentations.

What I want is to use [inser_line_after_match](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/chef/Chef%2FUtil%2FFileEdit:insert_line_after_match) function and the next line should be added with as much indentation as the regex line.

Is it possible?

For example - When I used

`file_xml.insert_line_after_match(/<cookie-path>\/analytics<\/cookie-path>/, "<cookie-secure>true</cookie-secure>")` -

The output is

```
<session-descriptor>
    <cookie-path>/analytics</cookie-path>
<cookie-secure>true</cookie-secure>
</session-descriptor>
```

What I want is the indentation to be maintained like -

```
<session-descriptor>
    <cookie-path>/analytics</cookie-path>
    <cookie-secure>true</cookie-secure>
</session-descriptor>
```

Also I know I can hard code the spaces, but then not always would I know about how many indents are getting used, so that solution is not the perfect one.

Answer (score 0):

Answer part one: FileEdit is an internal API to Chef and we do not support its use in recipe code. Do not do this. Period.

More useful answer: you need to manually include the requisite whitespace in your replacement string.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19190783)

Comment: Erm, what? While 50% of it is the unhelpful answer, I did include the actual answer too.

Comment: As a chef author I just cut an issue against core chef to deprecate and remove FileEdit because of all these questions.  We're not kidding that its a dead end and a source of endless pain and people need to stop using it.  https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/7043